# The correct usage of "to charge/debit somebody's credit card"

Tags: english-to-german, word-choice, idiomaticity

I have recently had confusion on how to correctly express the term "to charge/debit somebody's account/credit card" in German. I have always known "belasten" as the correct term for this, but then I was told the sentence

> Das Restaurant hatte meine Kreditkarte zu hoch belastet.

does not sound natural as a translation of

> The restaurant charged by credit card too much.

Instead, I was told that "abbuchen" sounds more natural in this case, so that

> Das Restaurant hatte zu viel von meiner Karte abgebucht.

is a better translation of "charge" in this context. This leads me to the following questions:

When does one use "belasten" and when does one use "abbuchen"?

Is it possible that *belasten* = debit/charge and *abbuchen* = debit/charge **from**?

Comment: Sounds perfectly fine for my ears. *Does not sound natural?* Sometimes people think, poor word choice is natural. 

Answer (score 6):

I'm afraid, you received debatable information. *Belasten* is correct without reasonable doubt (see, e.g. [DWDS](https://www.dwds.de/wb/belasten), meaning 2) and this does not restrict to cards but covers all types of accounts as well; it has however an accountant flavour and may be misinterpreted or not fully understood by any "insert non-financial non-expert group of choice".

Only accounts can be subjected to *Abbuchungen*, but due to the strict coupling one can argue, that the term equally applies to debit cards, where each payment directly maps to one *Abbuchung*.

I would not hesistate to keep using *belasten*.

Comment: Thank you. So, if I ask the waitress,

"Entschuldung, ich glaube, du hast meine Karte zu hoch belastet"

she will not laugh at me and will understand?

Comment: Not sure, depends on the waitress; I would prefer to say something less technical like *Entschuldigung, ich glaube, der Betrag stimmt nicht* in colloquial context.

Comment: @Mark: Depends on context/the type of the restaurant, but mostly, "Sie haben" would be more appropriate toward a random waitress than "du hast".

Comment: @O.R.Mapper thank you, yes, of course, my mistake. But "belasten" in this context sounds perfectly fine to you?

Comment: @Mark: Oh, I agree with guidot in that it sounds rather very formal for spoken language.

Answer (score 3):

@guidot is certainly right about the 'correct' term, but I would like to focus on colloquial speech, 'beyond good and evil', so to speak.

Colloquially, *abbuchen* and *Abbuchung* are arguably the most common way to talk about *every* kind of cashless payment in German when the specifics of the processing don't really matter in a conversation. Personally, I don't use other terms very often. The advantage is that it is universally understood.

Technically, however, an *Abbuchung* corresponds to a *direct debit* or a *debit card payment*. This requires a balance which is obviously different from how a credit card works. If this distinction is important to you, you probably should stay with *belasten*. If not, it would probably be appropriate when talking to your bank, for instance.

In everyday life, however, there is a reason why the debit terminology prevails: *direct debit* and *debit card payment* are by far the most popular *cashless* payment methods in Germany (while good old cash is still the most popular one – maybe because it eliminates the risk of the credit card being overcharged?). This is reflected by the fact that 95 % of the population own a [*Girocard*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Girocard), while only about 35 % have a credit card. The reasons for this might be that (1) the Girocard comes usually for free with the checking account and (2) it is needed to obtain the most popular payment method (i.e. cash) anyways.

#### Case study: Overcharge in the restaurant

> Das Restaurant <s>hatte</s> **hat** zu viel von meiner Karte abgebucht.

sounds extremely fine in my ears if you want to tell someone about, in fact a lot smoother than *hat meine Kreditkarte zu hoch belastet*. Talking about standard wording: note that the standard past tense (*Perfekt*) would be ***hat** abgebucht* ('charged'), while ***hatte** abgebucht* is past perfect ('**had** charged').

> You would say that "Entschuldi[gu]ng, ich glaube, [S]ie haben zu viel von meiner Karte abgebucht" would be an appropriate translation for "Excuse me, I believe you have charged my card too much"?

Definitely not inappropriate as a translation. If it is socially appropriate in the situation, of course, depends on some other factors like which kind of restaurant it is, how friendly the staff was etc. I see no problem with the wording itself, the rest depends:

- If you get the bill and you immediately notice the overcharge, of course you can point it out to the staff like that, or choose one of several other equally appropriate phrases. It's not offensive at all and gets the information across.
- But if you noticed it later and go to the restaurant separately, I would start with something along the lines of *Entschuldigung, dürfte ich Sie was zu der Rechnung von gestern Abend fragen? Ich glaube, …* ('Excuse me, may I ask you something about last night's bill? I believe...')

> Is it possible that belasten = debit/charge and abbuchen = debit/charge FROM?

No, actually *belasten*=*charge* and *abbuchen*=*debit*. But the problem when translating this terminology is that *charging* a bank account is different from *charging* a credit card. When charging a credit card, you get a credit that is due with the credit-card statement. When charging a bank account, the balance immediately drops. Hence, *to debit* is a special case of a *to charge* a bank account, but not the same as *charging* a credit card.

But what you got right is the syntax: It's *ein Konto<sub>ACC</sub> belasten* ('charge a bank account' – accusative object), but ***von einem Konto**<sub>PREPOBJ</sub> abbuchen* ('debit **from** a bank account' – prepositional object).

Comment: "This requires a balance which is obviously different from how a credit card works." - except that for some credit cards, customer communication talks about one's "Kontostand" and lists "Buchungen", which further blurs the line.

Comment: Thank you. i am now once again a bit confused. So, you would say that,

"Entschulding, ich glaube, sie haben zu viel von meiner Karte abgebucht"

would be an appropriate translation for, "Excuse me, I believe you have charged my card too much"?

Comment: @O.R.Mapper Yes, I think it's also possible to transfer money to the credit-card 'account' to raise the credit line.

Comment: @Mark I'll include that in my answer.

Comment: @amadeusamadeus Thank you very much for this explanation. Last question :) In your definitions, would it then make slightly more sense to say, perhaps, that the bank has accidentally "meine Karte zu hoch belastet", after I read my credit card statement? But a restaurant really does not do that. If this is the case, then maybe a slightly more informative definition of "X zu belasten" would be, "to put/apply a charge on X"? This is slightly more sophisticated, and something I would not say in restaurants, but would say about my bank.

Comment: @Mark (1) Answer is updated now. (2) I'm not so sure if I entirely got the question, but I'll try! You mean if the concepts of *belasten* and *charge*, resp., are equivalent and can be generalized as *to put/apply a charge on X*? Sure! *Belasten* can be used for credit cards *and* bank accounts. In every case, *debit* is a subset of the entirety of *charge*. It's a special way to charge a bank account.

Comment: @amadeusamadeus Yes, I think this very much clarifies things for me. I would not go to a waitress and say "You applied to high of a charge to my card.", as this sounds very official. Although I would say, "you charged my card too much", it's likely that "belasten" captures more of the former notion and not the latter, which clarifies my confusion.

Thank you for taking the time to answer my questions.

Comment: Was sollen denn die geschweiften Klammern in "Entschuldi{gu}ng, ich glaube, {S}ie haben zu viel …" bedeuten - dass die optional sind, nicht gesprochen werden?

Comment: @userunknown Die zitierte Frage wurde im zweiten Kommentar von oben zu dieser Antwort gestellt. Gemäß den üblichen Zitationsregeln habe ich korrigierte/geänderte Stellen zunächst durch eckige Klammern – »[« und »]« – gekennzeichnet, fand das aber weder markant genug noch gut lesbar. Alternativ habe ich daher geschweifte Klammern gewählt. Ich sehe aber ein, wenn auch das nicht gerade eindeutig ist.

Comment: @amadeusamadeus: Ah, das soll eine transparente Korrektur sein? Ich glaube, es ist nicht nötig und sinnvoll, über Flüchtigkeitsfehler, zusätzlich zur Versionierung, die GL ohnehin vollzieht, so penibel Buch zu führen. Dass Kommentare dann obsolet werden ist ja gewollt - deswegen werden sie auch gelegentlich von den Mods gelöscht. Wer an solchen Fehlern interessiert ist, kann über die Edithistorie diesen nachspüren. Ich frage mich, was so wertvoll an diesen ist, dass man sie ausstellen sollte.

Comment: @userunknown Sorry for switching back to English, but earlier I didn't notice that this originally was an anglophone question.---The only purpose of the braces was to make those very minor orthographic issues visible to Mark who posted the question like that in the comments; not because they were so severe (aren't) but on the contrary because they are so small that otherwise they would probably have been overlooked. Since the question *was* whether the phrase is correct, neither tacit correction nor take-over as is would have made sense. The value of the display is the chance to learn sth new.

Answer (score 0):

There is a gap between colloquial speech and legal terminology. Colloquially it does not make much difference to say

> Das Restaurant hat meine Kreditkarte zu hoch belastet

or

> Das Restaurant hat zu viel von meiner Karte abgebucht.

However, in Germany the juridical interpretation of the  word "abbuchen" is this: You must formally authorize another party to charge your account via a *[SEPA-Lastschriftmandat](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lastschrift)*. This is an official document and certainly has nothing to do with paying a bill in a restaurant or a shop. If you pay a bill via credit or debit card, then you confirm a single transaction by your signature or a PIN-code. That is, if your account is charged too much, then you were careless in the payment procedure. At least the PIN-code procedure makes sure that that your account is charged with the amount of money you confirmed. I am not an expert, but I could imagine that payment via credit card and signature is vulnerable to fraud.

My conclusion: The better variant is

> Das Restaurant hat meine Kreditkarte zu hoch belastet.